# Split an array into 2 based on objects property AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm having an array of objects These objects are coming from two different input fields on my form. They are identified by ids.

Field one is id:1 and field two is id:2. How can I split them into two arrays based on their ids. For example id:1 objects to be stored in array1 and id:2 in array2. I don't want to hardcode as if more input fields were created this would make some mess.

```
"values":[{"id":"1","description":"123"},
          {"id":"1","description":"456"},
          {"id":"2","description":"456"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you need to use `groupBy` as filter, if you interesting to figure out how it works read it

[angular-filter#groupby](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby)

> **Remember**
>   you don't need to make a new filter or other models to handle it just use it! **save your time**

but solution is so easy:

```
var result = $filter("groupBy")(values, 'id');
//this result will return 1: [{"id":"1","description":"123"},{"id":"1","description":"456"}] & 2: [{"id":"2","description":"456"}]
for(var item in result){
   //item return all keys (ids) => 1, 2
   //result[item] return all objects related to a key OR id
   //so you can do anything here
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make 'result' be an array instead of an object? I know you can wrap [ ] around values, however this makes it an array of an object of...

Comment: If you think about `groupBy` you figure out the result must be object, but for your answers YES we can convert it... see the update

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a list of uniques id by using *Set* . Then, with *array.prototype.reduce* along with *array.prototype.filter*,  you can dynamically build an object that wraps all the generated arrays for each id:

```js
var values = [
 {"id":"1","description":"123"},
 {"id":"1","description":"456"},
 {"id":"2","description":"456"}
];

var ids = [...new Set(values.map(v => v.id))];
var res = ids.reduce((m, o) => (m[`array${o}`] = values.filter(v => v.id === o), m), {});

console.log(res);
```